# Where shall I place "PHP SAML" library so that SAML Authentication module could find it?

Tags: 7

I have a multisite Drupal 7 installation (not using Composer), and I can't figure out where shall I place "PHP SAML" library so that the [SAML Authentication](https://www.drupal.org/project/samlauth) module would find it.

The instructions within the module simply say to install OneLogin's SAML PHP module (and the only provided instructions set uses Composer). The Libraries API module is installed, but wherever sites/domainname/libraries I try to place the content of the cloned https://github.com/onelogin/php-saml.git, the SAML Authentication module still says the "PHP SAML" isn't installed.

How and where do I place the right files in absence of Composer?

Comment: I placed mine in the root directory and added the library path in my settings.php: $settings['simplesamlphp_dir'] = '/path/to/library';

Comment: You know, it's possible to use Composer with Drupal 7. But even if you don't want to do that, there's nothing stopping you from using Composer to install simpleSAMLphp. It should show up in the `vendor` directory if you do this. You can do this in a separate repo and copy that into your project if you don't want to be able to update the code easily.

Answer (score 1):

I dabbled with this before. In order to get phpsimplesaml to work you need a module that autoloads composer libraries. I ultimately gave up trying it on d7 because it was a nightmare to get everything working, but I at least had the library recognized.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, I'll try "X Autoload" module first.